# Make a new defaut start viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xib, viewcontroller

I bought a quiz app template online and when the app starts the MainViewController it has the the questions categories on it. I want to add a main menu but when I add a new view controller  (called MenuViewController.h, .m, and xib) I can't figure out how to set it to be the default ViewController. I'm also not using storyboards I have .xib files for each ViewController. Please help.

Heres whats in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[QuizSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

    MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController] autorelease];
    [mainViewController release];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: check the `appdelegate.m` file. The code to set the `mainViewController` might be there in the `applicationDidFinshLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: can you post the code written in the `applicationDidFinshLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Comment: Okay I added the code that was in the AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code describes:

And instance of `MainViewController` is set as the content view controller of an instance of `UINavigationController`. This instance of `UINavigationController` is set to be the root view controller of the `UIWindow` (the main component letting your app show itself onto the screen).

Conceptually, it looks like this:
`MainViewController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIWindow` -> shows on the screen.

If you want to change the 'default' content, you will need to either replace `MainViewController` with your categories view controller or bypass the `UINavigationController` and set the root view controller of the `UIWindow` to your categories view controller.

So basically:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[QuizSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

    MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController] autorelease];
    [mainViewController release];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Or:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[QuizSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

    MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = menuViewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I modified the code, I had used CategoriesViewController instead of your MenuViewController class.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the MenuViewController.h by going to the top of AppDelegate.m and adding 
`#import "MenuViewController.h"`

Then in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions`

You should replace 
`MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];`

By
`MenuViewController *mainViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: Thanks for the help...I put everything into place. I added MenuViewController *mainViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  to my AppDelegate.m but now I'm getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT issue one {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}